# WebView как браузер по умолчанию или как открывать ссылки в своём браузере

Tags: java, android, webview

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
У меня есть простой браузер. Мне надо чтобы в нём открывались ссылки, как например в Google Chrome. Как это реализовать. Гуглил, нужного ответа не нашёл. Да и в манифесте всё что нужно прописал, но в менюшке он не алё. Помогите пожалуйста, если кто с этим сталкивался. Заранее спасибо

```
public class BrowserActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
    private static final String TAG = BrowserActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private String mCM;
    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUM;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mUMA;
    private final static int FCR=1;
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    EditText inputUrl;
    WebView webView;
    ImageButton forward, back;

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){


        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21){
            Uri[] results = null;

            if(resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK){
                if(requestCode == FCR){
                    if(null == mUMA){
                        return;
                    }
                    if(intent == null){

                        if(mCM != null){
                            results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCM)};
                        }
                    }else{
                        String dataString = intent.getDataString();
                        if(dataString != null){
                            results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            mUMA.onReceiveValue(results);
            mUMA = null;
        }else{
            if(requestCode == FCR){
                if(null == mUM) return;
                Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
                mUM.onReceiveValue(result);
                mUM = null;
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint({"SetJavaScriptEnabled", "WrongViewCast"})
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(ThemeUtils.getCurrentTheme());
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_browser);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=23 && (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(BrowserActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1);
        }

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        registerForContextMenu(webView);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.getSettings().setGeolocationDatabasePath(getFilesDir().getPath() );
        mSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swiperefresh);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(
            R.color.colorAccent);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebKit());

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                    progressBar.setProgress(newProgress);
                    if(newProgress==100)
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    else
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                @Override
                public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        request.grant(request.getResources());
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
                    callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
                }
                public boolean onShowFileChooser(
                    WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
                    WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams){
                    if(mUMA != null){
                        mUMA.onReceiveValue(null);
                    }
                    mUMA = filePathCallback;
                    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    if(takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(BrowserActivity.this.getPackageManager()) != null){
                        File photoFile = null;
                        try{
                            photoFile = createImageFile();
                            takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCM);
                        }catch(IOException ex){
                            Log.e(TAG, "Image file creation failed", ex);
                        }
                        if(photoFile != null){
                            mCM = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                        }else{
                            takePictureIntent = null;
                        }
                    }
                    Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                    contentSelectionIntent.setType("*/*");
                    Intent[] intentArray;
                    if(takePictureIntent != null){
                        intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
                    }else{
                        intentArray = new Intent[0];
                    }

                    Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
                    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
                    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, R.string.img_chooser);
                    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
                    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FCR);
                    return true;
                }
                public class Callback extends WebViewClient{
                    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.not_app, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                private File createImageFile() throws IOException{
                    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
                    String imageFileName = "img_"+timeStamp+"_";
                    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
                    return File.createTempFile(imageFileName,".jpg",storageDir);
                }
            });

        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRefresh() {
                    webView.reload();
                }
            });


        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    if( URLUtil.isNetworkUrl(url) ) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (appInstalledOrNot(url)) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                        startActivity( intent );
                    } else {

                    }
                    return true;
                }

                private boolean appInstalledOrNot(String uri) {
                    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
                    try {
                        pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
                        return true;
                    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                    }

                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                }

            });

        WebSettings webset = webView.getSettings();
        webset.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webset.setAllowFileAccess(true);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21){
            webset.setMixedContentMode(0);
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        }else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19){
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        }else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19){
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }

        CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(false);
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String search_bar = intent.getStringExtra("search_b");
        webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webView.clearFormData();
        webView.getSettings().setSavePassword(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true); 
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT ); 
        webView.clearCache(false); 

        if ( !isNetworkAvailable() ) {
            webView.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK );
        }

        webView.loadUrl("https://duckduckgo.com/?q=" + search_bar);

        webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {       

                @Override
                public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimeType, long contentLength) {
                    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));

                    request.setMimeType(mimeType);
                    String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
                    request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
                    request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
                    request.setDescription("Download file");
                    request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
                    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
                    DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                    dm.enqueue(request);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.download_toast, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
    }

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService( CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE );
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }

    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        if(webView.canGoBack()){
            webView.goBack();
        }else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        Boolean password = mSharedPreferences.getBoolean(getString(R.string.pass_t), false);
        Boolean cookies = mSharedPreferences.getBoolean(getString(R.string.cookie_t), true);
        Boolean cacheWeb = mSharedPreferences.getBoolean(getString(R.string.cache_t), true);
        Boolean fontLarge = mSharedPreferences.getBoolean(getString(R.string.font_t), false);
        Boolean supportJavaScript = mSharedPreferences.getBoolean(getString(R.string.js_t), true);
        Boolean navButtons = mSharedPreferences.getBoolean(getString(R.string.nav_but_t), false);

        if (password) {
            webView.clearFormData();
            webView.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);
            webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(false);   
        }

        if (cookies) {
        CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
        }

        if (cacheWeb) {
            webView.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
            webView.clearHistory();
            webView.clearCache(true);

            if ( !isNetworkAvailable() ) {
                webView.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE );
            }
        }
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(supportJavaScript);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(supportJavaScript);

        if (fontLarge) { 
            webView.getSettings().setDefaultFontSize(20);
        } 

        if (navButtons) {
            showNavButtons();
        } else {
            hideNavButtons();
        }
    }


    void hideNavButtons() {

        ImageButton mWebViewBackButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.mWebViewBackButton);
        ImageButton mWebViewForwardButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.mWebViewForwardButton);

        mWebViewBackButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mWebViewForwardButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }

    void showNavButtons() {

        ImageButton mWebViewBackButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.mWebViewBackButton);
        ImageButton mWebViewForwardButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.mWebViewForwardButton);

        mWebViewBackButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mWebViewForwardButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

    public void WebViewGoForward(View view) {

        if (webView.isFocused() && webView.canGoForward()) {
            webView.goForward();
        }

    }

    public void WebViewGoBack(View view) {

        if (webView.isFocused() && webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();      
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
            finish();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы открыть ссылку, пришедшую из другого приложения, нужно взять её из интента и отдать в `WebView`:

```
String url = getIntent().getDataString();
if (url != null) {
    webView.loadUrl(url); // если есть ссылка - открываем её
} else {
    webView.loadUrl(START_PAGE); // иначе открываем какую-либо стартовую страницу
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите статью Александра климова о WebView
http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/mybrowser.php

Надеюсь это вам поможет.

Comment: Прошу прощения, всё работает но при открытии ссылки в моём браузере ищет значении null. Это происходит с любыми ссылками. Как можно исправить эту проблему? Посмотрите кусок моего кода, может он поможет в ответе на мой вопрос

Comment: @Dmitry_777, так вы вместо картинки лучше код свой покажите и стектрейс ошибки. *"но в менюшке он не алё"* - как из этой фразы можно понять что именно у вас работает не так?

Comment: @woesss смотри, прикрепил